# Since there is conditional probability, is there any thing like conditional measure?

Tags: measure-theory

If I have two measure space $X,Y$, with measure $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$, the usual way to define a measure for the combined measure space $U=X \times Y$, is the product measure, i.e.,
$$\mu_U = \mu_X \times \mu_Y$$

However, this implies the independence between $X$ and $Y$, in my case, I want to define a measure that has dependency on each other. The corresponding idea would be define a conditional measure, 
$$ \mu_{U} = \mu_{X} \mu_{Y|X} $$
It is possible? Has any one heard about anything like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes these are called [Markov kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel). In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177730032), on page 229, he also define the conditional probability using the Radon-Nikodym theorem.